# Why are my div boxes widening whenever a large text is written?

Tags: html, css

i had been working on a project in the past days but i came across with a visual error that show my boxes doesn't have a proper right margin.

i had tried changing the flex on css but i didn't get other good results to fix this so i ha to scrap that idea

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #003300;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #00b300;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #004d00;
}

.post {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  background-color: #404040;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.link {
  background-color: #19194d;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #0c0c27;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #003300;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #00b300;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #004d00;
}

.post {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  background-color: #404040;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.link {
  background-color: #19194d;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #0c0c27;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}


/* Flex container */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Make post larger than form */

.post {
  flex: 3;
  margin-left: -65%;
}

.form {
  flex: 1;
}

.tema {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.thumbnail {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.titulo-tema {
  text-align: center;
}

.boton-tema {
  background-color: #00b300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.boton-tema:hover {
  background-color: #004d00;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.container-temas {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  ul {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .post {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: -40%;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .form {
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  li {
    padding: 70px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .titulo-tema {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  ul {
    margin-left: 35%;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .post {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: -80%;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .form {
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  li {
    padding: 70px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .titulo-tema {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1030px) {
  ul {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .post {
    margin-left: -65%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .form {
    margin-right: 70%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }
  li {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .titulo-tema {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>math lizard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <a href="">
        <li>tema 1</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>tema 2</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>tema 3</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container-temas">
    <div class="tema">
      <img src="" class="thumbnail">
      <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
      <hr>
      <p class="descripcion-breve">Esta descripcion demuestra que tema se esta explicando</p>
      <a href="">
        <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tema">
      <img src="" class="thumbnail">
      <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
      <hr>
      <p>Esta descripcion demuestra que tema se esta explicando</p>
      <a href="">
        <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tema">
      <img src="" class="thumbnail">
      <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
      <hr>
      <p>Esta descripcion demuestra que tema se esta explicando</p>
      <a href="">
        <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tema">
      <img src="" class="thumbnail">
      <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
      <hr>
      <p>Esta descripcion demuestra que tema se esta explicando</p>
      <a href="">
        <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tema">
      <img src="" class="thumbnail">
      <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
      <hr>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus tincidunt vehicula. Sed nec ante molestie, dignissim sapien et, finibus felis. Mauris a enim eget sapien laoreet interdum id a tellus. Duis blandit et lorem non aliquet. Vivamus
        id tellus ut eros finibus tempor ac ac sem. Etiam lacinia nisl eu varius ullamcorper. Vestibulum finibus ligula aliquam ipsum fringilla, nec luctus dolor ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur est est, aliquet
        ut commodo at, luctus sit amet nunc. Aenean in aliquet neque, vitae commodo tellus. Nulla et semper massa. Quisque tristique turpis ante, non semper libero fringilla a. Praesent et arcu id massa semper iaculis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; </p>
      <a href="">
        <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i just expect to get a proper margin so this problem won't happend everytime a long text is posted on the index

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/tqvm4ujx/3/

Comment: Your HTML is also **invalid**...the links should be **inside** the `li`. `ul` can only have `li` as children.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to tell exactly where you are wanting your end result to be, and I cannot comment due to the fact I don't have 50 reputation. However, after looking over the code, rather than doing a flexbox, you could simply add a "width: 40%" to the .tema class. This will keep the divs from expanding into the other area (I personally don't think the margin is the best way to go with it, at least it isn't what I would do.) Here is the code for this, if I am understanding what you want your end result to be correctly (having the large text div not overflow into the right area). This should at least fix part of the area, but note this code does not fix your media queries nor other classes.. I hope I answered this in the way you were looking

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #003300;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #00b300;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #004d00;
}

.post {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  background-color: #404040;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.link {
  background-color: #19194d;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #0c0c27;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #003300;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #00b300;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #004d00;
}

.post {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  background-color: #404040;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.link {
  background-color: #19194d;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #0c0c27;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}


/* Flex container */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Make post larger than form */

.post {
  flex: 3;
  margin-left: -65%;
}

.form {
  flex: 1;
}

.tema {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 40%;
}

.thumbnail {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.titulo-tema {
  text-align: center;
}

.boton-tema {
  background-color: #00b300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.boton-tema:hover {
  background-color: #004d00;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.container-temas {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  ul {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .post {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: -40%;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .form {
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  li {
    padding: 70px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .titulo-tema {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  ul {
    margin-left: 35%;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .post {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: -80%;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .form {
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  li {
    padding: 70px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .titulo-tema {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1030px) {
  ul {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .post {
    margin-left: -65%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .form {
    margin-right: 70%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }
  li {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .titulo-tema {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <a href="">
      <li>tema 1</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li>tema 2</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li>tema 3</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container-temas">
  <div class="tema">
    <img src="" class="thumbnail">
    <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
    <hr>
    <p class="descripcion-breve">Esta descripcion demuestra que tema se esta explicando</p>
    <a href="">
      <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tema">
    <img src="" class="thumbnail">
    <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>Esta descripcion demuestra que tema se esta explicando</p>
    <a href="">
      <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tema">
    <img src="" class="thumbnail">
    <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>Esta descripcion demuestra que tema se esta explicando</p>
    <a href="">
      <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tema">
    <img src="" class="thumbnail">
    <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>Esta descripcion demuestra que tema se esta explicando</p>
    <a href="">
      <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tema">
    <img src="" class="thumbnail">
    <h2 class="titulo-tema">titulo del subtema</h2>
    <hr>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus tincidunt vehicula. Sed nec ante molestie, dignissim sapien et, finibus felis. Mauris a enim eget sapien laoreet interdum id a tellus. Duis blandit et lorem non aliquet. Vivamus id
      tellus ut eros finibus tempor ac ac sem. Etiam lacinia nisl eu varius ullamcorper. Vestibulum finibus ligula aliquam ipsum fringilla, nec luctus dolor ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur est est, aliquet
      ut commodo at, luctus sit amet nunc. Aenean in aliquet neque, vitae commodo tellus. Nulla et semper massa. Quisque tristique turpis ante, non semper libero fringilla a. Praesent et arcu id massa semper iaculis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus
      orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; </p>
    <a href="">
      <p class="boton-tema">Entrar</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```